# Opensource Content Filtering

Tags: content-filter

We are planning to introduce a web content filtering on our newly created LAN environment. I am inclined towards opensource alternatives to ISA server. I came across uTangle and they seem to have a free of charge version.

Would you recommend Utangle in an environment of 50users on a 2GB RAM, 80GB HDD, Core2Duo or P4 workstation ?

Any other free opensource alternatives for content filtering would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squid and Dansguardian are a reasonable solution if I understand what you are looking for.

Also check out:

Censornet - http://www.censornet.com/

IPCop - http://www.ipcop.org/

Smoothwall - http://www.smoothwall.org/

SME Server - http://wiki.contribs.org/Main_Page

Comment: censornet isn't free - if I have read right on there website, was unable to download anything from them. - thanks for the suggestions I will have a look at them !! thanks alot !

Comment: They used to be. I did find this:

http://opensource.censornet.com/download/

See if that let's you download.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the level of complexity you need, OpenDNS provides web site filtering based on blocking DNS resolution.

The problem with open source solutions is you need to continuously refine the categorization  sites that drive the filters.  This requires a pretty steady and significant effort.  I suspect OpenDNS has solved this.  I am not sure what other projects may have tackled it.